# How to get information of client that access to our app

Tags: web-services, websocket

I am new in programming, now I build in server side for my app team, we do on web service.
when client login to my app, I am service provider. how I can get and know my client proxy, client IP address, my client from web(google chrome or Firefox) or android or iOS mobile ? I see google can do it. how i can like google? please any idea to improve my application. welcome for all suggestion.

Comment: did u googled ??? what efforts u tried

Comment: I see this [this](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) but wish to get any seguest more

Comment: You need to add more details to your question in order for people to be able to help you, e.g. what technology specifically you are using on your backend.